# SAP Business One Export To ASCII Format

Tags: ascii, sapb1

I'm trying to find a way to print a Business Partner Aging Report in ASCII format.

The customer needs the report to be printed in this format for a South African bank as part of their prerequisites. I'm assuming it's so that the bank can import the file into their system.

I've been able to print to ASCII format in another piece of software called Sage Pastel Partner but I've been battling to find a solution in SAP Business One.

Any help or guidance would be massively appreciated.

Thanks,
B

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? Note that requests to recommend software aren't on topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi. I'm asking if there is a way to export directly to ASCII format out of SAP Business One when viewing Business Partner reports like the aging analysis.